# Upper bound on smallest eigenvalue of correlation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for an upper bound on smallest eigenvalue of an n x n correlation matrix, which is symmetric and positive semi-definite (with all the diagonal entries as 1).

Most of the results on the internet (e.g. Gershgorin circle theorem) can only give lower bounds.

EDIT:
**What do I know so far?** 
A trivial upper bound would be 1, since the matrix is positive semi-definite and the trace is n.

I can also show that the least eigenvalue of any correlation matrix is always smaller than that of any of its principal minors that is formed by eliminating $i^{th}$ row and $i^{th}$ column for any $i \in [1,n]$. If we recursively apply that, we can show that it would apply to any $k \times k$ sub-correlation matrix, $\forall k \in [1,n-1]$. One of the answers below highlights the special case for $k = 2$.

However, I am wondering if there exists a more precise upper bound in terms of the entries of $\Sigma$?
Any ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ denote the snmallest eigenvalue of the matrix and call the matrix $A$. You have $\lambda = \min_{\|x\|=1}x^TAx$. Hence,
$$
\lambda\le e_1^TAe_1 = 1.
$$
But we can do better than that. Let $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $i\neq j$. With $x_\pm = 2^{-1/2}(e_i\pm e_j)$ (satisfying $\|x_\pm\|=1$) we have (denoting the columns of $A$ by $a_k$)
$$
x_\pm^TAx_\pm = \frac 1 2(e_i \pm e_j)^T(a_i \pm a_j) = \frac 1 2(a_{ii} \pm 2a_{ij} + a_{jj}) = 1 \pm a_{ij}.
$$
Thus, $\lambda\le 1-|a_{ij}|$ for all $i\neq j$ and so
$$
\lambda\,\le\,1 - \max_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|.
$$

Comment: Thanks @amsmath!
I knew about this bound as well. Let me know if you find anything further tighter in terms of entries of correlation matrix.

Comment: So, why did you waste my time by not saying this? I don't like this at all.

Comment: My apologies. I have finally updated my post with all the bounds that I know so far.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a trivial one:

the sum of all eigenvalues is the trace, so it is $n$. This means that the smallest must be $\le 1$.

Comment: And this bound is achieved by the smallest eigenvalue of the  identity matrix.

Comment: Haha, yeah I know that! :)